# Django: Counter templatetag across multiple templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I found this [template tag](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2619/) which allows me to run a counter inside a template. I have this requirement where I need to render out nested paragraph numbers but I can't use a CSS counter (for various reasons).

The problem I run into with the above mentioned template tag is that it only works inside the context of the template that includes the tag library. Unfortunately I do have a lot of different templates to include and the counter has to work across all of them with the same instance.

Is there a way to accomplish this with modifications on the given template tag or is it possible to get this done in any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, never mind. Should have thought a minute longer. Sticking itertools.count() into the template context does the job.